# Множественная обработка формы Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

На странице несколько полей с разными именами, по умолчанию - по одному:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

Данные сериализуются и передаются AJAX'ом.
На стороне PHP принимаю так:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $params);
// POST PARENT
$_POST['name[]']     = $params['name'];
$_POST['lastname[]'] = $params['lastname'];
```

Далее валидация CI:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Parent name', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[10]|alpha');
```

При валидации получаю ошибку:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1172</p>
```

Из ошибки ясно, что летит на обработку массив, а не строка...Но раньше при поступлении массива name, и задания правила name[] - все работало прекрасно...

Полный код валидации:

```
// PARENT VALIDATION
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Parent name', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[10]|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname[]', 'Parent secondname', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[14]|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('status[]', 'Status', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('area[]', 'Sector', 'required|integer');      
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('street[]', 'Street', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[3]|max_length[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('block[]', 'Block', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile[]', 'Mobile', 'required|min_length[8]|man_length[9]|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone[]', 'Phone', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[9]|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email[]', 'Return email', 'xss_clean|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('apart[]', 'Apartament', 'numeric');

            // CHILDREN VALIDATION
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nameChild', 'Child name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[10]|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastnameChild', 'Child secondname', 'required|trim|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[14]|alpha');  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('kindergartner', 'Gradinita', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('streetChild', 'Child Street', 'required|trim|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[3]|max_length[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('area', 'Area', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('sex', 'Sex', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('limba', 'Limba', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('idnp', 'IDNP', 'required|trim|min_length[13]|max_length[13]|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Code', 'trim|required|exact_length[5]|alpha|callback__captcha_check');
```

Comment: Покажите ваш весь код валидации

Comment: НА 1172 строке идет проверка на is integer. смотрите где вы используете эту проверку "|integer"

Comment: Дописал полный код валидации в вопросе

Comment: А нет ли у вас массива в массиве?
А то так и пишет:
"Хочу принять строку, а вы даете массив"
Посмотрите в профайлере, что вы передаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вижу странность:

```
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('area[]', 'Sector', 'required|integer');
```

и

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('area', 'Area', 'required|integer');
```

В первом случае вы валидируете area как массив.
В во втором случае вы валидируете строку, а в форме вы передаете массив. скорее всего из за этого и проблемы...

P.S. Что говорит о баге в фремворке. Но я не уверен. посмотрите еще раз внимательно форму и проверьте.

Comment: Сейчас проверю, возможно

Comment: Но если из за присланных с клиента данных мы получаем критическую ошибку, то это Конкретный баг в фреймворке

Comment: Все тоже самое...'area' заменил на имя 'areaChild' - ошибка таже

Comment: А закомментируйте вообще вадидацию с area. Что теперь?

Comment: Нашел ошибку - поле kindergartner, оно было без[], а данные содержало как массив. Спасибо всем

Comment: Я же тебе говорил) Удачи)

Comment: Получается, что в библиотеке валидации нет проверки на входящие данные и они тупо подставляются в функции проверки значений. А какая версия фреймворка?

Comment: ВЕРСИЯ: 2.1.4, посмотрите на Git класс валидации, может вы скажете правду, баг или нет. Спасибо